# Unable to assign large value to AD custom attribute

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to assign a value to the custom Active Directory attribute `msExchRecipientTypeDetails` for a user account as below, but it's resulting in an "unspecified error" COM exception.  I'm not seeing this problem with other custom attributes (including others related to MS Exchange), nor with small values (e.g., 1) on the right side of the assignment.  It doesn't seem to be security-related.  How do I resolve this?

```
using (DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
{
    userEntry.Properties["msExchRecipientTypeDetails"].Value = 2147483648;
    userEntry.CommitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `msExchRecipientTypeDetails` attribute is of type `IADsLargeInteger`, which is AD's way of storing `long` (64-bit) integers.  The number must be converted to `IADsLargeInteger` before being assigned.

This does the conversion:

```
using ActiveDs;

private IADsLargeInteger LongToAdLong(long inputValue)
{
    IADsLargeInteger outputValue = new LargeInteger();     // 64-bit
    outputValue.HighPart = (int)(inputValue >> 32);        // 32-bit
    outputValue.LowPart = (int)(inputValue & 0xFFFFFFFF);  // 32-bit

    return outputValue;
}
```

Using that, you can now assign the value to the attribute:

```
using (DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
{
    var mailboxTypeValue = LongToAdLong(2147483648);
    userEntry.Properties["msExchRecipientTypeDetails"].Value = mailboxTypeValue;
    userEntry.CommitChanges();
}
```

As an aside, if you are directly assigning values to AD Exchange attributes as part of a process to provision mailboxes for new users, *don't do this* as it is unsupported and will result in email issues, some of which may not be obvious.  A better way would be to use the PowerShell API to call into an appropriate PowerShell command, such as `Enable-RemoteMailbox`.